# Encrypting message containing public key with another public key

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto

I have two asymmetric key pairs client_key, A and another_key, B.
I want to send a encrypt a dict with B's public key. However, the dict must contain A's public key, like the following example:

```
message_dict = {
  'hostname': socket.getfqdn(),
  'request': 'MY_REQUEST',
  'client_pub_key': client_key.publickey().exportKey(),
}
```

I did a `json.dumps` of the above and encrypted with B's public key. After I decrypt it, I do not get the same message. I noticed that it goes wrong only if I include `client_pub_key` in the dict.

I have been looking for answers online and this is possibly why it might be going wrong:

- The message is too long to encrypt with B's public key
- The `client_pub_key` has special characters which leads to a situation where JSON encoding is messed up

I tried the following:

- Used `pickle` instead of JSON
- Used `binascii.hexlify` to encode `client_pub_key`
- Used `base64.b64encode` to encode `client_pub_key`
- Used `Crypto.Util.RFC1751.key_to_english` to convert to some characters `client_pub_key`
- Set B's key 2048 bytes and A's key 1024 bytes

All my above efforts failed. Hence I'm here looking for help.

**My Question: How do I encrypt a message of the above dict format so I can send it over to the server?** 
(I'm using thrift's `TTornadoStreamTransport` and `TBinaryProtocol`, if that helps)

My test code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import base64
import binascii
import json
import pickle
import socket

from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Util.RFC1751 import key_to_english

client_key = RSA.generate(1024)

message_dict = {
  'hostname': socket.getfqdn(),
  'request': 'MY_REQUEST',
  'client_pub_key': int(binascii.hexlify(client_key.publickey().exportKey()),16),
}

another_key = RSA.generate(2048)

print '\n\nDICT: {0}'.format(message_dict)
message = json.dumps(message_dict)

print '\n\nMESSAGE: {0}'.format(message)
encrypted = another_key.publickey().encrypt(message, 32)[0]

print '\n\nENCRYPTED: {0}'.format(encrypted)

decrypted = another_key.decrypt(encrypted)
print '\n\nMESSAGE: {0}'.format(decrypted)

result = json.loads(decrypted)
print '\n\nDICT: {0}'.format(result)
# result should be same message_dict
```

Comment: answer is always: don't encrypt data with RSA, only encrypt symmetric .e.g. AES keys with RSA and encrypt the data with AES.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I understand that concept. My data is the key itself. Let's take the dict out of the question for now.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
I have a client machine A and server machine B. The client has B's public key. 
I want to generate RSA pub-pvt key pair on client machine (A) **dynamically**, when a request is to be made to the server (B). The dynamically generated key A's public key is sent as part of request to server B. 
A's public key will be used by B to send messages to A. 
Do you have any thoughts on how to get this process done.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be, that the message which you try to encrypt should be never larger than the n-modulo!

Because:

cipher = message ** e (mod N)

If your message is numerically larger than the RSA module (in your case 2048 BITS - not Bytes), you won't get the correct ciphertext, and decription will never work. (mathematically)

In your case this happens.

You should be careful, because I guess, that after the json.dumps() the message should not larger than (in your case of the 2048bit another_key) 2048//8 = 256 bytes long - you can test it after json.dumps() via len(message).
In your abovementioned example the length of your message will be larger than 700 bytes... and 700 > 256.

Just to show the meaning of this:
first try a message with exactly 256bytes of length:

```
>>> import json
>>> from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
>>> another_key = RSA.generate(2048)
>>> message_dict = {'t':'a'*248}
>>> message = json.dumps(message_dict)
>>> len(str(message))
256
>>> enc = another_key.publickey().encrypt(message, 32)[0]
>>> dec = another_key.decrypt(enc)
```

You will see, in this example the length of the message is exactly 256 bytes (not bits, but 256*8 = 2048 bits) long - and it works fine!

But now let us try a length of 257 bytes (more than the length of the n modulo (2048 bits = 256 bytes):

```
>>> import json
>>> from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
>>> another_key = RSA.generate(2048)
>>> message_dict = {'t':'a'*249}
>>> message = json.dumps(message_dict)
>>> len(str(message))
257
>>> enc = another_key.publickey().encrypt(message, 32)[0]
>>> dec = another_key.decrypt(enc)
```

In this case dec != enc - because the message is numerically larger than the n modulo.

If you will mathematically understand the reason for this, take a look in the meaning of "cipher = message ** e (mod N)" ;)